# generating excel in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to create an excel sheet in ruby on rails. So I used the plugin Rexcel. When I am running the application I am getting the following error.

**uninitialized constant Rexcel::Workbook::Builder**

I had added the following code, then this error hitting

```
workbook = Rexcel::Workbook.new

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Customers")

worksheet.add_line("name","test")

headers['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="excel-export.xlsx"'
headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0'
headers['pragma']="public"
workbook.build
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for Rails 3.x or some other version? Also, please post the stack trace of the error.

Comment: yes, i am looking in rails 3.0. The full trace follows..
---------------------------------------------------
 NameError in FormadminController#download

uninitialized constant Rexcel::Workbook::Builder
vendor/plugins/Rexcel/lib/rexcel.rb:210:in `build'
app/controllers/formadmin_controller.rb:192:in `download'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'

Answer (score 8):

I would advice to use Spreadsheet instead of Rexcel because is definitely more mature and I'm using it with Rails 3 with no problems.

[Here is the documentation.](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/)

The overall process would be:

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet = book.create_worksheet :name => 'Customers'
sheet.row(0).concat %w{Name Country Acknowlegement}
book.write '/path/to/output/excel-file.xls'
```

Answer (score 5):

+1 to tommasop

I'd like to add. If you, like me, you consider this as presenting data, just like xml, html or json, you don't want to write to disc. Heroku is read-only if you're considering using that.

I would change the `book.write '/somepath..'` to

```
def xls
  .. your stuff .. 
  blob = StringIO.new("")
  book.write blob
  blob.string
end
```

then, in the controller do

```
send_data @customer.xls, :type => :xls, :filename => @customer.xls_file_name
```

remember to add the mime type in your initializer NOTE, I just realized that these examples are from my rails 2.3.10 app. Maybe it differs in rails 3.

```
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.ms-excel", :xls
```